# Help with the proof of Nagell-Lutz Theorem from Silverman's AEC

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

From Silverman's AEC, Chapter 8, Section 7:
I am trying to prove Nagell-Lutz theorem using the Theorem 7.1, which is

[image: Theorem 7.1]

In this theorem $K$ is a number field. Now if I have an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ as $E: Y^2 = x^3+Ax +B$ where $A, B \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Suppose $ P \in E(\mathbb{Q})$ is nonzero torsion point of exact order $m$. Then I need to show that $x(P), y(P) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The book says that for the case $m = p^n$, a prime power and $ p > 2$, since $r_v =0$ the result follows immediately.

I am trying to explain this as follows:

We note that ord$_v(p) = 1$ if $v=p$,  $0$ if $v$ is a finite(that is, not $\infty$) prime different from $p$.

In any case, $r_v =0$. So, by part (b) of this theorem we have, ord$_v(x(P)) \geq 0$ and ord$_v(y(P)) \geq 0$ for all (finite)primes $v$. Thus $x(P), y(P) \in \mathbb{Z}_v$ for all primes $v$ (Sorry for the unusual notation for the ring of padic integers). Thus $x(P), y(P) \in \mathbb{Z}$. (Can't seem to recall why this basic fact is true).

I would really appreciate it if someone here could check my proof and help me fill the holes in the book's proof.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of a rational number $x$ with respect to *all* finite primes is nonnegative, then the denominator of $x$ (in lowest terms) must be 1, since if any prime $q$ were to divide the denominator then the order of $x$ with respect to $q$ would be negative. Hence $x$ is an integer.

I think that's all you're missing, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense!